# Wrong output encoding rendering with scalascraper

Tags: scala, encoding

```
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL.Extract._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL.Parse._

object Scraper {
  val browser = JsoupBrowser()

  val doc = browser.get("http://camhr.com")

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     // Extract the <span> elements inside #menu
     val items = doc >?> element("#footer")
    print(items)

   }

}
```

What I see in website is in English, but when I run this code I get in Chinese in my console (IntelliJ IDE).

How to get the right english text rendering ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
val url = "http://camhr.com"

val doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
  .header("Accept-Language", "en")
  .get
```